# Tensorflow predictions change as more predictions are made

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, skflow

I'm using tensorflow 0.8.0 and skflow ([or now known as learn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn)). My model is very similar to this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/text_classification_character_cnn.py) but with a dnn as the last layer (similar tot he minst example). Nothing very fancy going on, the model works pretty well on its own. The text inputs are a max of 200 characters and 3 classes.

The problem I'm seeing is when I try to load the model and make many predictions (Usually around 200 predictions or more), I start to see results vary.

For example, my model is already trained and I load it and go through my data and make predictions.

```
char_processor = skflow.preprocessing.ByteProcessor(200)
classifier = skflow.TensorFlowEstimator.restore('/path/to/model')

for item in dataset:
    # each item is an array of strings, ex: ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'world']
    line_data = np.array(list(char_processor.transform(item)))
    res = classifier.predict_proba(line_data)
```

If I load my classifier and only give it one item to predict upon then quit, it works perfectly. When I continue to make predictions, I start to see weirdness.

What could I be missing here? Shouldn't my model always return the same results for the same data?

Comment: If your model uses the skflow implementation of batch normalisation that could be a source of the changes.  The current implementation updates the moving averages during validation - see [this pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/2104).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not doing any batch normalization. I still tried patching my tensorflow with that pull request and I still have the same issue, unless I need to retrain my model?

Comment: If you are not using batch normalization then it is not the source of your problem and you can ignore my comment and link.  Retraining would not be necessary.

Comment: This issue looks similar to mine https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2167

Comment: That issue does seem to be the case. When I remove the dnn this isn't doesn't seem to happen anymore.